# If/else statements just do not seem to be working in Javascript and i don't know what I am doing wrong

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to get this to work for a Javascript magic 8 Ball, and for the life of me i cannot figure out what the issue is, so i am hoping someone on here will be able to tell me what I am doing wrong. I will pose the code as it is now:

```
let userName = "Vince";
if (userName === true){
  console.log(`Hello ${userName}`);
} else {
  console.log(`Hello!`);
}
let userQuestion = "";
if (userName === true){
  console.log(`${userName},You asked me \"${userQuestion}\"`);
} else {
  console.log(`You asked \"${userQuestion}\"`);
}
```

I have also tried

```
let userName = "";
userName === true
  ? console.log(`Hello ${userName}`)
  : console.log("Hello!");
let userQuestion = "";
userName === true
  ? console.log (`${userName},You asked me \"${userQuestion}\"`)
  : console.log(`You asked \"${userQuestion}\"`);
```

No matter what i do here, it will only ever run the "else" section of code so i am getting this:

Hello!
You asked "will i win the lottery"
It is decidedly so

I have no doubt that the answer is obvious and I am being dense, or i have just misunderstood something about truthy/falsey statements, but i am very close to pulling my hair out at this stage, so any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

i have switched the above around and tried loads of different things. Just a bit lost.

Comment: `"Vince"` isn’t `true`. Why do you expect a boolean to equal a string? What is the expected outcome? A check if `userName` is truthy looks like `if(userName){`…`}`.

Comment: The string `"Vince"` is never `true`, nor is `""`.

Comment: Please also note that `===` doesn't check truthy/falsy values, instead `===` is [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality)

Comment: Note: You can check out this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) for more info on how `===` and `==` work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to compare two different data types: `userName` is a String, while `true` is a boolean value, that is why the if condition is never satisfied.

The correct way to check for `userName` would be:

```
    if (userName){
console.log(`Hello ${userName}`)
} else{
console.log(`Hello!`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fault lies in the datatype youre checking. You expect a bool but your are giving it a string.

I assume you want to check if there is a name and not empty?

````
let userName = "Vince"

if (!!userName){ //Checks if username is not empty.
console.log(`Hello ${userName}`)
} else{
console.log(`Hello!`)
}```
````

Comment: It also might be a bit clearer for your comment to say `//Checks if userName is not empty` (rather than "...is empty").